# Python list generation from two strings

Tags: python, list

can you help me get output like this by using bellow data:

```
name='suraj,rohit,rahul'
score='34,45,55'
```

I want to make a list like this:

```
[['suraj', 34], ['rohit', 45], ['rahul', 55]]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
list(zip(name.split(','), score.split(',')))
```

> [('suraj', '34'), ('rohit', '45'), ('rahul', '55')]

EDIT

People wanted lists instead ot tuples and int instead of strings, here we go:

```
[[x, int(y)] for x, y in zip(name.split(','), score.split(','))]
```

> [['suraj', 34], ['rohit', 45], ['rahul', 55]]

Comment: to exactly match OP's expected output, maybe also map score to int :)

Comment: This is a list of tuples, not a list of lists and the score is not an integer

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension.

```
[[i,int(j)] for i,j in zip(name.split(','), score.split(','))]
#[['suraj', 34], ['rohit', 45], ['rahul', 55]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a list, you can use a dictionary in order to make it more efficient while making it work properly at the same time. Please refer to the following code I have provided below in order to make your program much more better.
code:

```
 name=""
 score=""
 Dictionary={"suraj,":34,"rohit,":45,"rahul":55}
 for A,B in Dictionary.items():
     name=name+A
     score=score+str(B)+","
 print(name)
 print(score)
```

I hope this cleared your doubt

Answer (score 0):

you can combine map() and zip() functions to get list of list,also to conver list of sting into list of integers:

```
name='suraj,rohit,rahul'
score='34,45,55'

print (list(map(list, zip(name.split(','), map(int,score.split(','))))))
```

output:

```
[['suraj', 34], ['rohit', 45], ['rahul', 55]]
```

you can also use basic for loop:

```
name='suraj,rohit,rahul'.split(',') # get list of names
score='34,45,55'.split(',') # get list of scores


result = []
for i in range(len(name)):
    result.append([name[i],int(score[i])])

print (result)
```

output:

```
[['suraj', 34], ['rohit', 45], ['rahul', 55]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda function instead:

```
    print(list(map(lambda x,y: [x,y], name.split(','), score.split(','))))
```